# prometheus query to pull a kubernetes node by label and list only certain fields

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Team,
I am not finding good tutorial on prometheus query hence asking here. basically, I want a tutorial that teaches how to use query in pulling kubernetes nodes and making grafana charts dashboards.

one of my question is: how to pull k8s node by label and list all those nodes with only one of their label

my query is below

```
(kube_node_labels{label_team_role="services"})
```

output

```
kube_node_labels{endpoint="http",instance="10.23.109.27:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="d.8xlarge",label_beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_kubernetes_io_hostname="node2",label_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_kubernetes_io_role="node",label__msre915="services",label__server_type="cpu",label_service="workflows",label_sysctl_fs_mqueue="allowed",label_nodeGroup="cpu",label_nodeType="cpu",namespace="monitoring",node="mlwkr1k8s0301d",pod="-monitoring-kube-state-metrics-79d8ddb6c7-prhs5",service="monitoring-kube-state-metrics"}    1
kube_node_labels{endpoint="http",instance="10.23.109.27:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="d.8xlarge",label_beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_kubernetes_io_hostname="node1",label_kubernetes_io_role="node",label="services",label_node_scheduler="mmm",label_erver_type="cpu",label_service="workflows",label_sysctl_fs_mqueue="allowed",label_nodeGroup="cpu",label_nodeType="cpu",namespace="ing",node="node2",pod="v-monitoring-kube-state-metrics-79d8ddb6c7-prhs5",service="monitoring-kube-state-metrics"}
```

expected

```
node1 label_kubernetes_io_hostname="node1"
node2 label_kubernetes_io_hostname="node2"
```